# Why my useState, does not reprint the array with the new elements in it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, use-state

Why my useState, does not work property?
In a filter search bar, I'm trying to reprint the elements of an Array depending on the input  but I can't get the reprinting right,

```
const clickSearchIcon = (query) => {
    let filteredItems = [];
    console.log('ITEAM ALL:', itemsAll); //works --> 9
    setItems(itemsAll); //DONT work, --> 1st time: 9 , second time: 0; both times must be 9
    console.log('items:', items);
    //filtrar items que concuerdan con el query
    items.map((item) => {
      if (item.title === query) return filteredItems.push(item);
    });
    //repintar item filtrado con el query
    setItems(filteredItems); //does work
  };
```

this is the [complete file](https://github.com/doberman7/tiendaDeGarage/blob/search-filter/frontEnd/src/pages/ItemsAll.js), in case you need more context

[This is the browser and console.logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di883.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

`itemsAll` has never changed so you don't need to update it in `clickSearchIcon` function. To filter items, you can use `filter` instead of `map`.

```js
const clickSearchIcon = (query) => {
  const filteredItems = items.filter((item) => item.title === query);
  setItems(filteredItems);
};
```

Comment: try it, but keeps only reprinting the 1 time...     :(

Answer (score 0):

`allItems` has never been changed. `setItems` does not see it has been changed. because `allItems` is an array, although you changed its items, but the object itself (think it as a pointer) has not been changed.

Just use a new variable, make a copy of `allItems`, and use `setItems` on the new variable.

```js
let newItems = [...allItems]
// modify newItems
setItems(newItems)
```